# How can I bring Color from a material into geo nodes and use it as a filter?

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, color, masking, optimization

First time posting here. I've been scratching my head on how to do this for some time now, and I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm looking to create a detailed texture(Solid black and white) in shading that will act as a filter for separation of a mesh inside of geo-nodes. I can't seem to figure out how to bring the shader material into geo-nodes.

The purpose of this is to separate the mesh based on the color by creating new edges along the intersection of black and white, while keeping the solid colored faces of the object light in terms of mesh detail.

I've been able to accomplish this by using noise/other textures directly in geo nodes while subdividing the mesh(6+ times), but that results in an extremely necessary amount of detail(1,500,000 vertices). Operating on that heavy of a mesh crashes blender.

I can't seem to be able to do this process while maintaining both stability of the program, and the level of detail that I need to prevent a dual colored 3d print from showing a pixelated texture. Can anybody help me figure this out? I appreciate you taking the time to read this!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Bad news for you: The values created with a shader cannot be processed in *Geometry Nodes*, because the shader works as the last element in the chain. However, if you had a texture beforehand, it would be possible, because you can also hook it into *Geometry Nodes*.

Comment: Shoot! Thanks for the response! So, I guess my next question is, can I bake the shader material onto my object, and then use that image texture as a detailed mask to cut new geometry onto my object in geo nodes?

Comment: Yes, you can of course bake the result you create with the shader. And then you can use this texture in *Geometry Nodes*. By the way, there are already some good answers to both processes here, so you don't need to ask the question again. Please use the search function of this platform.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the help! It's very much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget that the use of textures in *Geometry Nodes* works best if you have created a UV map beforehand, so that you can use this texture correctly on your geometry. All the best!

Comment: very helpful and easy to miss tip. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use anything from shaders in geometry nodes, since geometry nodes is calculated first - and anyway it wouldn't help you.

However Higgsas did make a node that may do what you are looking for that interpolates faces based on a gradient texture (only on triangle, though. I want to make one that works for all n-gons or quads and have some ideas, but haven't hade time).

This is the [link](https://blenderartists.org/t/higgsas-geometry-nodes-groups-blender-3-1-3-0/1351737/65?page=2#:%7E:text=marching_triangles_surface.blend%20(158.4%20KB))